# How to add CSS to a class through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery Mobile for a simple mobile app, and I want to add a CSS to it. Currently I have the following CSS for the class.

```
.home-button-edited {
    border: 1px solid #2373A5;
    margin-top: 1px !important;
    background:#3496da;
}
```

Then in JS part I have the following code segment:

```
var viewport = {
    width: $(window).width(),
    height: $(window).height()
};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", setHomeButton, false);

function setHomeButton() {
    var difference = viewport.width - 85;
    $('.home-button-edited').css("left", "difference !important");
}
```

The point is that, I want to add a left property to .home-button-edited, with the value that I get in the difference variable, and it also should have an !important property. Any ideas?

Comment: try `$('.home-button-edited').css("left", difference);`, the way you have it you are setting `difference` as a string and not using the variable.

Comment: share me the link of you code

Comment: !important is bad, best solution is to get rid of it in the CSS to start.

Comment: @epascarello But I really need it for my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use in your case:

```
$('.home-button-edited').css('cssText','left: '+difference+'px !important');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.home-button-edited').css("left", difference+"!important");
```

or

```
 $('.home-button-edited').style.setProperty( 'left', difference, 'important' );
```

Comment: Anyway `!important` statement doesn't work using jQuery `css()` method

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, it seems to completely ignore the !important part. Any idea how to achieve what I want in JS or jQuery?

Comment: Try something like this (just grabbed a snipped from somewhere else)"

$( '.myclass' ).each(function () {
    this.style.setProperty( 'height', '0px', 'important' );
});

Comment: @ett Use attribute style or `.css('cssText','left: '+difference+'px !important');` or better, don't use `!important` statement in any rules

Comment: @A.Wolff And what exactly is 'cssText' part?

Comment: @A.Wolff By the way, it works. If you can write it as an answer. I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Error in your function.

```
function setHomeButton() {
    var difference = viewport.width - 85;
    $('.home-button-edited').css("left", difference + " !important");
}
```

Comment: `!important` statement doesn't work using jQuery css() method

Comment: @MayankTripathi Yes, A. Wolff is right, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: O yes.. My mistake.. it does not. Apologies!